# $S = \{\frac{1}{2015}, \frac{2}{2015},...,\frac{2014}{2015}, \frac{2015}{2016}\}.$ Replace any $a, b$ by $a + b - 5ab$ $2014$ times. Find new $S.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Here's the full problem statement:

> $S = \{\frac{1}{2015}, \frac{2}{2015},...,\frac{2014}{2015}, \frac{2015}{2016}\}.$ Remove any numbers $a, b$ from $S$ and replace it by $a + b - 5ab.$ Repeat this process $2014$ times and $S = \{\frac{m}{n}\}$. Find $\frac{m}{n}$ (reduced).

Someone posted this problem in a Facebook group and it was supposed to be solvable by a middle school student. I honestly have no idea where to start other than recognizing that the process reduces 1 element after each iteration, so it makes sense that there is only $1$ element left after $2014$ iterations. I'd love to hear some guidance. Thank you!

Comment: The denominator of each of the values is $2015$ except for the last one, which has $2016$ instead. This seems somewhat unusual, so is it possibly a typo?

Comment: I don't know either. Still, instead of 2014,  do the same task for 2  and see what happens. I guess (1/3,2/3, 3/4)

Comment: @JohnOmielan hi, it was indeed $\frac{2015}{2016}$, (i.e. no typo).

Comment: @WillJagy Hi, I tried the denominators $3$ and $4$ and there doesn't seem to be any pattern. I guess the number $5$ in the combination formula is unique to the denominator $2015.$

Comment: trying $a+b - 3ab$  instead, seems to work.

Comment: Note that $(1-5a)b =0$ when $a = 1/5$

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful insight, Will and Brian!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ or $b$ is $1/5$, then $a+b-5ab=1/5$.

In other words, as long as $1/5 \in S$ and $S$ is finite, we don't care what else is in $S$.  By the end of your game, the only remaining number will be $1/5$.

To finish, just note $1/5=403/2015 \in S$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to arrive at $1/5$ too!

Comment: In general, if $S$ is a finite set and at each step one replaces the pair $(a,b)$ by $a+b-kab$ for a fixed $k$, then the last number remaining is $\frac{1}{k} (1-\prod_{x\in S} (1-kx))$. The reason is that the transformation $x\mapsto 1-kx$ changes the operation to the product.

Comment: @CatalinZara Hi, I'm struggling to understand your remark. Could you pls elaborate further? Thank you!

Comment: @ten_to_tenth In the language of algebra, Catalin Zara is talking about a homomorphism.  Essentially, we use the fact that $(1-ka)(1-kb) = 1-k(a+b-kab)$ to change the strange-looking rule in your question to a nicer one where you just multiply the numbers.  What this means, in the philosophy of algebra, is that any expression of the form $a+b-kab$ where $k\neq 0$ is just multiplication, but we've disguised the identities of the numbers.  In this sense, the solution I gave just shows us that $1/5$ is playing the role of $0$ (as of course multiplying anything by $0$ still gives us $0$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring I can't say I fully understand your explanation, but I believe it's entirely a problem on my part, as I'm not familar with these more advanced concepts. I wish to revisit your comment in the future when I'm more mathematically mature. Thank you very much!

Comment: Homomorphisms are categorically the most important objects in algebra, but they're also the first stumbling block in algebra for mathematics students (sometimes even mathematics graduate students), so don't feel bad if my short attempt at explanation doesn't _click_.  I don't know if it would be sufficient for a mathematics student's first encounter.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for your encouraging words. I'm a first year CS student (who's trying to learn as much math as I could). Hopefully I'll be able to understand these concepts soon in my mathematical journey! Once again, thank you very much!